# Unmanaged code with file access fails in a .NET/C# application

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, dllimport, unmanaged

Here's the scenario I am confronted with:

- in a simple DLL, written in C, there are functions which access files, for example:

```c
DLL_EXPORT void Virt_Hello(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("Hello_world", "w");
    if (f) {
        fprintf(f, "Hello world!\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

- in the managed code:

```cs
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void Virt_HelloDelegate();
private IntPtr m_helloPtr;

m_helloPtr = GetProcAddress(m_libraryPtr, "Virt_Hello");
Virt_Hello =  Virt_HelloDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(m_helloPtr, typeof(Virt_HelloDelegate));
```

- and later, this function is called as:

```cs
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
public void Hello()
{
    Virt_Hello();
}
```

I've been reading for the last couple of days pretty much everything I could find on this topic however it still doesn't work: the file is not open, and the calling managed code/process just hangs - no exceptions are thrown either.
Tried `StdCall` calling convention, changed several parameters on the `SecurityPermission` attribute - to no avail. I've even made sure all assembly dependencies are signed.
Of course I would prefer to integrate it through C++/CLI instead of PInvoke-ing however the DLL is a blackbox for me.
Any help or suggestion how to go forward would be much appreciated.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious but right now I just can't see it.

My best regards to the community!

Comment: *"Of course I would prefer to integrate it through C++/CLI instead of PInvoke-ing"* So why not do that? Anyway, don't just try calling conventions randomly. Find out what calling convention the DLL is using for its exported functions. Where exactly does the calling process hang? When you break in with the debugger, what line of code does it break on? On the call to `Virt_Hello`?